# Php check string for correct format

Tags: php, string

Looking for some help on how to validate a string in PHP.

My string contains:

- 4 NUMBER
- 1 LETTER
- 5 NUMBER

all in one entry, so  like `1234A12345`.

I need to make sure/validate this before inserting in the DB.

Can one of the wizard help me out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty simple regex:

```
/^\d{4}[a-zA-Z]\d{5}$/
```

And [in case you haven't used regex in PHP before.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: `code`
$regex = '/\d{4}[a-zA-Z]\d{5}/'; 
if (!preg_match($regex, $myref)) {
    die('Please ensure the reference you enter is in the correct format.');
}
`code`

Comment: @SaloCine: You can indicate code inline by surrounding it with backticks (\`), `like this` (actual text looks like \`like this\`).